# Redirection within Django using Classbased (generic) views

Tags: python, django

I have created a functional Django (1.11.5) system which allows me to add numerous Bikes to Manufacturer due to the foreign key capabilities. Unfortunately I can't get my head around how I correctly can redirect user to (PrimaryKey) Manufacturer after the user has updated the Bike information. My views uses Class Based Views for deleting, creating, and updating both the Manufacturer and Bikes.

Below I have displayed both the views.py and URL.py I have within my App.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .models import Manufacturer, Review


class ReviewUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Bike
    fields = ['bike_body']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manufacturers:index')
```

**URLs.py**

```
url(r'bike/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.BikeUpdate.as_view(), name="bike-update"),
```

Comment: yes it is, currenlty I get redirected to home page after update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is override the `get_success_url` method on your view.

```
class ReviewUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Bike
    fields = ['bike_body']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('the-url-you-want', args=(your_key,))
```

More info about the recently saved object can be found at `self.kwargs`.

Comment: How can I make they args key dynamic? would I need to use kwargs? args works if I add a number manually but in that case after every edit function the user gets redirected to the specific "ID" details page. as of yet the code looks like `return reverse('bikes:detail', args=(1,))`